# Combinatorics Question. Id like a thorough explanation. Especially the part about multiplying or dividing each side and when its OK to do so.

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

The question is : ${n \choose 3} +{n \choose 2}+{n \choose 1}$. and it says to write the following expression without using the factorial symbol. Thanks in advance.

The answer I got was $n^4 - \frac {3n}{6} + n^2 - \frac n2 + \frac n1$

Comment: Could you define $C_{k}$?

Comment: You mean the formula? like n! / r!(n-r)! ? Also, how do you guys make the letters big or small like that?

Comment: unless I am misreading your formula simplifies to $n^4+n^2$.

Comment: I will reformat your question.  After it is done, click on edit to see how the formatting is done.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help!

Comment: Just to note:  for $n=3$ the original expression is $1+3+3=7$, no?  But your polynomial appears to give $3^4+3^2$ which is certainly not $7$.

Comment: Does anyone know the answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

The notation $n C k$, read "$n$ choose $k$" and alternatively denoted $\binom{n}{k}$, means:
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$
So then
$$\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{3} + \binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{1} &= \frac{n!}{3!(n-3)!} + \frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!} + \frac{n!}{1!(n-1)!} \\
&= \frac{1}{6}n(n-1)(n-2) + \frac{1}{2}n(n-1) + n \\
&= \frac{1}{6}n^3 - \frac{3}{6}n^2 + \frac{2}{6}n + \frac{1}{2}n^2 - \frac{1}{2}n + n \\
&= \frac{1}{6}n^3 + \frac{5}{6}n
\end{align*}$$
I believe the answer you gave was incorrect.

Comment: Why is it 1/6n? you can do it that way? Sorry. I appreciate everyones help btw thank you.

Comment: No need to be sorry. the coefficient is $\frac{1}{3!} = \frac{1}{6}$. Then the polynomial part is $\frac{n!}{(n-3)!} = \frac{n \cdot (n-1) \cdots 1}{(n-3) \cdots 1} = n(n-1)(n-2)$.

Comment: So we can make n! Just 1? Because there has to be a 1 in the numerator right?

Comment: ...I don't follow. $n!$ is the product of all the numbers from 1 through $n$. $(n-3)!$ is the product of all the numbers from 1 through $n-3$. When you cancel out all the numbers that appear in both numerator and denominator, you are left with the product of $n \cdot (n-1) \cdot (n-2)$.

Comment: Just because it goes from *n!* / 3!(n-3) to *1*/6n(n-1).

Comment: The $1/3!$ is $1/6$. The $n!/(n-3)!$ is $n(n-1)(n-2)$.

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry Haha. I'm still learning this stuff its very confusing. Just had no idea you could turn it into a n fraction. (I think the course I'm taking is very poor at explanations.) Thank you very much for your time and patience

Comment: Did your teacher say $(n^3 + 5n)/6$? Parentheses are important.

Comment: Yes, just as you put it, my bad.

Comment: When you are not sure of an answer given by a book or a teacher, try to compute some values. Here, taking $n=3$ directly shows it is impossible to have $n^{3}+\frac{5}{6}n$.